# Zariski openness of Zariski dense representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated group and let $G$ be an almost simple algebraic group defined over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Consider the representation variety $R$ for $\Gamma$ in $G$. Namely, for any commutative $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$-algebra $A$, $R(A)$ is identified with $\operatorname{Hom}(\Gamma, G(A))$.  Then $R$ exists and is an affine $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$-scheme of finite type.

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. Let $R_o\subset R(K)$ be the subset consisting of Zariski dense representation $\Gamma\to G(K)$. My question is: can we conclude that $R_o$ is Zariski open in $R$ (which could be empty)?

This question indeed has a positive answer in the case of characteristic zero. See Proposition 8.2 of [A'Campo and Burger - Réseaux arithmétiques et commensurateur d'après G.A. Margulis](https://math.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/math/department/Research/Research_Groups/Burger/1994_Reseaux_arithmetiques.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Let $K=\overline{\mathbb F}_p$. I claim there are no Zariski dense representations $\varphi\colon \Gamma\to G(K)$. Let $g_1,\dots,g_d$ be generators of $\Gamma$. Then $\varphi(g_i)\in G(K)$ so there is some $n_i>0$ such that $\varphi(g_i)\in G(\mathbb F_{p^{n_i}})$. Then letting $N:=n_1\cdots n_d$, we have $\varphi(g_i)\in G(\mathbb F_{p^N})$ for each $i$. In particular, $\varphi(\Gamma)$ lies in $G(\mathbb F_{p^N})$. But $G(\mathbb F_{p^N})\subset G(K)$ is a finite subset, hence is Zariski closed.

(In particular, when $K=\overline{\mathbb F}_p$, $R_o=\emptyset$ so is Zariski open in $R$.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think that it does not contradict o my question as it is Zariski open (though empty). Note that $R_o$ is allowed to be empty.